# Recursively trying to rename files in Mac OS terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, find, rename

I have a many subfolders with files containing the text `mainLine` in them. I want to strip that text and rename all files recursively.

For example I'm trying to rename `log12 mainLine.txt` to `log12.txt`, I'm trying the following code:

`find . -exec  rename -nvs '*  mainLine*' '' * {} +`

But I'm getting files which contain that pattern as unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

There are many versions of `rename`, and to my knowledge none of them are installed by default in Mac OS; but the options you used suggest you are using one which expects file names to rename as the third and subsequent arguments. You apparently copy/pasted it from somewhere without understanding it. You should replace the `*` with the files you want to rename, or better yet, run it once per directory with the wildcard intact.

```
find . -type d -execdir sh -c "rename -nvs '* mainLine*' '' *" \;
```